# Return results in specific radius

Tags: qgis

I have a list of some 3,000 locations (Site List A) that I would like to bounce off of another list of some 10,000 locations (Site List B). All locations are in csv format with the Lat and Longs in decimal format.  Ideally an output of this would be in a csv or excel format showing if a location in Site List A falls within a 1/4 mile and 1/2 mile radius of a location in Site List B it would list Site list A's location with the site/sites from Site List B that met that criteria.

I am completely new to QGIS and have spent a few hours now trying to get familiar with the program and make some steps toward progress but have made no meaningful progress.  Is there something in QGIS that would make this a little easier or suggestion for another solution to accomplish this task that someone could provide?

Comment: STOP SHOUTING. Text in ALL CAPS is more difficult to read and understand, and won't get you help any faster. It's also rather impolite to SHOUT at people you're asking to donate their time to help you. And what you SHOUTED in the title was irrelevant noise that shouldn't have been there at all. Please take the time to read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to load each table into QGIS as a spatial layer. You need to turn the lat/long pairs into a geometry field. You also need a useful ID and other attributes on each point. "Create Points Layer from Table" in the processing tool tab. I always project the layers to a planar projection when loading especially before doing any analysis. Otherwise most tools produce nonsense units assuming the spherical coordinates are planar units. You also then have normal map units preferably metres and kilometres. Convert them to Freedom Units later.

The Qgis processing tab has lots of prebuilt tools to create the data you need in a single step. For example a "Distance Matrix" which makes up a table of from-to distances. It can be limited to k nearest, but not by distance. This would reduce the size of the matrix. I would put it in a database, not a spreadsheet.

Conceptually you could draw a buffer circle around each of the 3000 points, select within the circle and then do a Distance Matrix. But resist this thought. GIS is set up to avoid endless loops by users, the tools are optimised to avoid looping, similar to the way that SQL does not require you to loop over each record.

If you have the matrix then you could filter by distance to reduce the size.